# tiny-slider not centering images properly

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to use [tiny-slider](https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider), small vanilla js carousel lib but I'm having issues centering the image when displaying only one item per slide.

```js
        var slider = tns({
            container: '.slide',
            items: 1,
            mode: 'carousel',
            slideBy: 'page',
            autoplay: false,
            mouseDrag: true,
            center: false,
            nav: false
        });
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
ul {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.1/min/tiny-slider.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.9.1/tiny-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container"> 
<ul class="slide">
<li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/720x460" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/720x460" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/720x460" alt=""></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I tried using `display: block; margin: 0 auto;` to images, but the images are slightly off to the right.

The github issue pages haven't been helpful with this specific case, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each li produced by tiny-slider has a class of 'tns-item'.
You need to add a css rule for that like :

```
li.tns-item{
    text-align:center;
}
```